# How to properly override (or create my own) Pandas read_csv method?

Tags: python, pandas, overriding

I am trying to write my own read_csv method on top of pandas.read_csv.

```
# pandas_custom.py module
import pandas as pd
def read_csv(**kwargs):
    df = pd.read_csv(**kwargs)
    df = df.apply(my_function)
    return df

# main_module.py module
import pandas_custom as pdF
df = pdF.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='train.csv') # WORKS
df = pdF.read_csv('train.csv') # TypeError: read_csv() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Who can I properly create my own read_Csv method or override original? Should I just copy all the params from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html and paste them into my custom read_csv method?

Comment: change your `read_csv` to `def read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, **kwargs)` or, yes, copy the header in the doc to your code.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? There are different possible solutions including explicitly calling your new function, replacing the function in a subset of your program, or replacing the value globally (dangerous). But without knowing additional context it is difficult to arrive at a conclusion.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. I have to read csv file in a specific way, and I have to do that in all the places I read csv. So instead of df=pd.read_csv();df=df.apply(); I wanted to my the logic inside my own read_csv method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pass an argument to your function, but your function only accepts kwargs. Try:

```
def read_csv(*args, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_csv(*args, **kwargs)
    df = df.apply(my_function)
    return df
```

Comment: Haha! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.